# C, I am having a memory issue I think

Tags: c

I have the following struct

```
struct matrix_t {
    int m;
    int n;
    double * data;
} matrix_t;
```

Which gets initialized and returned in a method.

```
struct matrix_t * makematrix(char * NAME){
    ... 
    static struct matrix_t data;
    data.m = m;
    data.n = n;
    data.data = &matrix[0][0];
    return &data;

}
```

I call this method from main

```
int main() {

    ...
    struct matrix_t * makematrix(...);
    printf("%lf\n", matrix1->data[4]);
    printmatrix(matrix1); // this is discussed right below
```

The correct element is printed out with `printf`. I then try to pass it to another call

```
printmatrix(matrix1);
```

which tries to do the exact same print statement

```
void printmatrix(struct matrix_t * matrix){
    printf("data point %lf\n", (matrix->data[4]));
```

But here it prints a 0.000 which is wrong. Is my data array getting deallocated? I've been banging my head. Whats going on.

Reproducing example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>


struct matrix_t {
    int m;
    int n;
    double * data;
} matrix_t;


//void printmatrix(int m, int n, double *matrix){
void printmatrix(struct matrix_t * matrix){
    printf("MATRIX: \n");
    printf("M %d \n", matrix->m);
    printf("N %d \n", matrix->n);
    printf("data point %lf\n", (matrix->data[4]));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix->n; j++){
            //printf("%d\t", i* matrix->n + j);
            //printf("%lf\t", matrix->data[i* matrix->n + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

struct matrix_t * readfile(char * NAME){
    // Function for reading input files and returning data.

    FILE *fptr;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int linenum = 0;
    //array size
    int m;
    int n;

    if ((fptr = fopen(NAME,"r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }


    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1) {
        if (linenum==0){
            sscanf(&line[0], "%d %d", &m, &n);
        }
        linenum++;
    }

    //allocate mxn matrix
    double matrix[m][n];

    fclose(fptr);
    fptr = fopen(NAME,"r");
    linenum=0;
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %d", &m,&n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    static struct matrix_t data;
    data.m = m;
    data.n = n;
    data.data = &matrix[0][0];



    printf("testing \n");
    printf("%lf\n", data.data[4]);

    return &data;
}



int main()
{
    char filename1[] = "Amat.dat";
    char filename2[] = "Bmat.dat";
    struct matrix_t * matrix1;
    //struct matrix_t * matrix2;
    matrix1 = readfile(&filename1[0]);


    printf("%lf\n", matrix1->data[4]);

    printmatrix(matrix1);
    //matrix2 = readfile(&filename2[0]);
    //printmatrix(matrix1);
    //printf("test %lf", matrix1[0][0]);
    return 0;

}
```

prints:

```
testing 
4.000000
4.000000
MATRIX: 
M 4 
N 4 
data point 0.000000
```

where a file might look like

```
2 2 
1 2 
3 4
```

Comment: Where does `matrix` come from in `makematrix`?

Comment: See [mcve]......

Comment: it's read in from a file. matrix is defined as     `double matrix[m][n];`

Comment: So *explain* and *show* what that means. We can only guess what the problem is if you hide details like that. Is that `static`? Is it dynamically allocated? If not, you've got problems.

Comment: Tip: You should have a `typedef` here to omit `struct` but then you go and ignore that and just use `struct matrix_t` anyway. Your current `struct` definition is incorrect, it *creates a single variable called `matrix_t`* which you just happen to never use. The pattern is `typedef struct X { ... } X`.

Comment: I've added my entire script, I thought it'd be easier to break it down. Let me try to understand your comments in the meantime. I'm new to C. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check that `sscanf()` returns 2; if not, you've got problems.  Always check inputs.

Comment: Note that all-capital letter names (like `NAME`) are normally reserved for macros — and occasionally types like `FILE` or `DIR`.  They're not normally used for variables.  It's not formally wrong; it is just unusual.

Comment: `sscanf()` is only used to read in `m` and `n` both of which have no problems.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure I understand your `static` comment.

Comment: @user267298 `data.data = &matrix[0][0];` That points to a local variable that ceases to exist once `readfile` returns, but the pointer is saved in the `static struct matrix_t data;` which gets returned.

Comment: @dxiv but it works in main()...? is that still explainable?

Comment: @user267298 That's [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), which means anything is allowed to happen, including the appearance that it may sometimes "work". "*why do m and n not cease to exist*" They do, but their values are saved in the `static struct` before the function returns.

Comment: oh gosh, ok. Thank you that is very helpful! But I can't move the declaration of `matrix` outside of read file because it gets the size from the file...

Comment: You need to be hyper-aware of object lifetimes in C, as any non-`static` local variables turn into *ghosts* after you exit the scope they're defined in unless you've dynamically allocated their contents with things like `malloc()`. A ghost might look real, but it's an illusion that can disappear or change without warning.

Comment: Ok, so by dynamically allocating with `malloc()`, `matrix` should cease to disappear? Let me try that!

Comment: It worked!! Thank you tadman and dxiv so much for your help and thorough explanations.

Comment: As noted in an answer, including `<iostream>` suggests you are compiling a C program with a C++ compiler. This sometimes works, but they are not the same language, and doing so complicates the process.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not really clear what exactly the question is I will assume that you are not understanding why your minimal example prints what it does.

Sadly you describe a non-reproducible problem: if I use your example and the given dataset (2 2 \n 1 2 \n 3 4) I get (unsurprisingly):

```
testing
0.000000
0.000000
MATRIX: 
M 2 
N 2 
data point 0.000000
```

When printing "testing" and a datapoint (data.data[4]) in line 76 you go out of bounds of your 'defined' array. If you change the 4 to something between 0-3 the data is output correctly.

Now, having changed that the testing does work, but the printmatrix() still show our data point as 0.000

```
testing 
4.000000
4.000000
MATRIX: 
M 2 
N 2 
data point 0.000000
```

An explanation for that was already given as a comment to OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112607/c-i-am-having-a-memory-issue-i-think#comment116886580_66112607). A much better example to see this is to change the output in main to:

```
printf("%lf\n", matrix1->data[0]);                    
printf("%p\n", matrix1->data);                                   
printf("%lf\n", matrix1->data[0]);
```

This corresponds to:

```
1.000000
0x7fffcf8f6b40
0.000000
```

As stated in the comments, this is called undefined behavior in C. Stuff might or might not work, nobody knows.

So, how do we fix it? I did remove all irrelevant lines of code in the example and added a solution (along with some QoL additions). Of course it depends heavily on what you want to achieve. Instead of declaring your matrix static in the readfile function (which might lead to obfuscated code), you can dynamically allocate the memory. I think that my solution is not pretty, but it should show sufficiently how to allocate memory.

```
//man getline
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


struct matrix_t {
    int m;
    int n;
    double * data;
};


void printmatrix(struct matrix_t * matrix){
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix->m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix->n; j++) {
      printf("%lf\t", matrix->data[i* matrix->n + j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
}

/*
 *  we assume that the file NAME contains a matrix of the form
 *  m n
 *  {DATA}
 *
 *  where {DATA} is a N x M Matrix, delimited by spaces
 *
 *  we do not check if the file corresponds to this format! beware of dragons
 *
 *  onError: set matrix to NULL
 */
void readfile(struct matrix_t * matrix, char * NAME){

    FILE *fptr;

    if (!(fptr = fopen(NAME,"r"))){
      perror("error! opening file");
      matrix = NULL;
      return ;
    }

    int n,m;

    fscanf(fptr, "%d %d", &m, &n);

    int matrix_size = n * m;
    matrix->data = calloc(matrix_size, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++) {
      fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &matrix->data[i]);
    }

    matrix->n = n;
    matrix->m = m;

    return;
}



int main() {

  struct matrix_t * matrix = malloc(sizeof(struct matrix_t *));
  if(!matrix)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  readfile(matrix, "Amat.dat");
  if(!matrix)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  printmatrix(matrix);

  puts("testing");
  printf("%lf\n", matrix->data[0]);                    
  printf("%p\n", matrix->data);                                   
  printf("%lf\n", matrix->data[0]);

  free(matrix->data);
  free(matrix);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now we get:

```
1.000000        2.000000
3.000000        4.000000
testing
1.000000
0x5591fadc34b0
1.000000
```

---

At last, some side notes about your code (unrelated to the initial question):

- you are including iostream, which is a C++ library, so either this is about C++ or the library should not be included
- Even if (or maybe specifically because) this is a minimal example, you should clearly comment on why things happen and what purpose they serve, so it is easier to understand by others (future-you included)

Comment: If you're going to `free(matrix)`, then you should also `free(matrix->data)` (beforehand). And your check for `if(!matrix)` should come *before* the call to `printmatrix(matrix)`.

Comment: valid point, although I am not sure about your second point? The check does come before printmatrix, or did you mean something else?

Comment: My mistake. I meant before calling `readfile(matrix, "Amat.dat")`.

Comment: of course, i forgot to also check the return value of malloc, thanks for spotting that!